# convert factor to date with empty cells

Tags: r, date

I have a factor vector `x` looking like this:

```
""
"1992-02-13"
"2011-03-10"
""
"1998-11-30"
```

Can I convert this vector to a date vector (using `as.Date()`)?

Trying the obvious way gives me:

```
> x <- as.Date(x)
Error in charToDate(x) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

At the moment I solve this problem like this:

```
> levels(x)[1] <- NA
> x <- as.Date(x)
```

But this doesn't look too elegant...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply need to tell `as.Date` what format to expect in your character vector:

```
xd <- as.Date(x, format="%Y-%m-%d")
xd
[1] NA           "1992-02-13" "2011-03-10" NA           "1998-11-30"

To illustrate that these are indeed dates:
xd[3] - xd[2]
Time difference of 6965 days
```

PS. This conversion using `as.Date` works regardless of whether your data is a character vector or a factor.

Comment: +1 For indirectly noting that as.Date() converts to character.

Answer (score 2):

When you pull in the data with read.csv, or others, you can set

```
read.csv(...,na.strings=c(""))
```

to avoid having to deal with this entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I usually convert factors to a POSIX* type class using the function `strptime`. First argument is your vector and the second argument is the "pattern" by which the date/time is constructed (a `%` sign + a specific letter). You basically tell R that first you have a year, then you have a -, then a month and so on. See `?strptime` for a full list of conversion specifications.

```
x <- factor(c("1992-02-13", "2011-03-10", "1998-11-30"))
(x.date <- strptime(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
 [1] "1992-02-13" "2011-03-10" "1998-11-30"
class(x.date)
 [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

The same principle holds for `as.Date`. You tell R to "make this a date/time object and here are the instructions on how to make it".

```
(as.Date(x, "%Y-%m-%d"))
 [1] "1992-02-13" "2011-03-10" "1998-11-30"
```

Comment: This is a dangerous habit since it introduces the possibility of subtle errors with time zones.  In general its best to avoid POSIXt classes for dates.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, what would be the alternative?

Comment: @RL, See the other answers to this post.  They don't use POSIXt classes.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, I didn't realize `as.Date` produces a different class. I haven't really worked with time/date that spans several time zones so I haven't paid special attention to this. Thank you for bringing it up.

Comment: @RL, See R News 4/1 help desk article.